# How to relate the regularized regression coefficients with their number in the plot?

Tags: regression

I have a model with 13 independent variables (all of them are significant and 2 of them are categorical variables) and 678 observations. I ran the ridge regression and lasso on the data set using glmnet package. Here is the output.

[image]

[image]

I was wondering how I can relate the variables to their number and what L1 norm mean.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "relate the variables to their number"? Each plot has thirteen series, corresponding to thirteen variables, presumably numbered in order of definition. What command did you run to create these plots?

Comment: I used  fit.ridge=glmnet(x,y,alpha=0,standardize=TRUE) and plot(fit.ridge,xvar="norm",label=TRUE) for ridge and similar thing for lasso. I'm not sure if the first number is my first variable etc. Can I the variables' name in the graph instead of their number. Thanks.